# What is the difference between node:lts-alpine3.14 and node:lts-alpine? which one should I use for node backend apis?

Tags: node.js, docker

What is the difference between node:lts-alpine3.14 and node:lts-alpine? which one should I use for node backend APIs?

I want to use one of the images for my Node backend APIs with the following:
Express
Mongo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. They're two tags for the same image.

What you want to consider is what you want to happen when 3.15 gets released. If you want to stay on 3.14, you should use `node:lts-alpine3.14`. If you want to move to 3.15 (or whatever the next release is), you should use `node:lts-alpine`.

To verify that they're the same image, you can go to https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags&page=1&name=lts-alpine and check that the digest values for the two tags are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! so, If a new node version becomes the LTS. like node 17. then it won't be updated in node:lts-alpine3.14?

Comment: `lts` refers to the node version. The newest LTS version is 16 and the next will be 18. 3.14 refers to the Alpine version. If you want to control both versions, you should use `node:16-alpine3.14` (which right now is the same image as the other two). `lts-alpine3.14` will be changed to node version 18 when that gets 'active' state which looks like it'll be in late 2022 according to this https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: `lts` refers to ***L***ong-***t***erm ***s***upport. If you just use `lts-alpine` you are telling the build to always use the latest long term support (LTS) version and you don't care what the version number is. If you want to be in control (say a new Node version might break your build), you can specifically define the version. Please note, you can also control both the version of node and alpine.